# How do I write an installer for a Windows SDK in Python?

Tags: python, installation, windows-installer, nsis

I understand that NSIS supports [plugins](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NsPython_plug-in), but I can't find an [NsPython](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NsPython_plug-in) tutorial.

Maybe first I should ask: if I can run Python code from NSIS, is it a good idea to script my installer in Python (instead of explicitly managing a stack in an NSIS script)?

And secondly: are there any good tutorials?

**Alternatively:** Is there another appropriate Windows installer scripting environment?  I don't think `wix` will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download the plugin archive that you linked, there is a readme file that describes the plugin's API as well as an example NSIS installer that uses the plugin.

Comment: Cool. I hadn't seen the bundled example.